# Gianni Morandi - C'era un ragazzo

Tags: cover

There is an Italian music written by Mauro Lusini called [C'era un ragazzo che come me amava i Beatles e i Rolling Stones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6c2uUq9yZQ).

Then made famous by [singing it with Gianni Morandi at Rai Uno](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=isCn3vGKXm4) just before being censored by Rai TV channel. Other famous versions are [Gianni Morandi - C'era un ragazzo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Or0A4Kj77k) and an older [version of same song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9nCFpzbol8).

Searching the Internet, I found the following passage (lacks sources) the story about this song:

> Gianni Morandi, the famous Italian singer in the 1960s, he recorded at
>   the request of the composer Mauro Lusini this song. **He made the first
>   English version**, Poorly, and showed Gianni, who loved and recorded as
>   a single in 1966, already rewritten in Italian.

There were two famous covers in Brazil. The first group: [Os Incríveis - Era um garoto que como eu amava os Beatles e os Rolling Stones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHuByPPRZS8) in 1970.

And the second: [Engenheiros do Hawaii - Era um Garoto Que Como eu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFsou8Szb3M) in 1990.

I wonder if there is any cover in british or american english of this song.

Comment: [Joan Baez](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCk9NMN_NVc), an american singer, covered it, but still in italian...